# Inserting implementation version to manifest using sbt

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010202/adding-vendor-information-to-manifest-mf-using-sbt-assembly)
that it is possible to manually insert specific fields to the manifest:

```
name := "project"
version := "2.3.5"

packageOptions := Seq(Package.ManifestAttributes(
                     ("Implementation-Version", "2.3.5")))
```

I would like to use `version` directly, without recopying the version number.

Putting `version` instead of `"2.3.5"` gives an error. Can I somehow use `version` directly, without recopying the version number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the value of a setting by calling `.value` on it like so

```
packageOptions := Seq(
  Package.ManifestAttributes(("Implementation-Version", version.value))
)
```

In general, [`value`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/8af7a5acaef783b69d0f4c88d348ac3d90c753ad/main-settings/src/main/scala/sbt/std/InputWrapper.scala#L198) can be called in the following scenarios:

> `value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting."